# getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my main.m

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Here is the code where i am getting error:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {   
  currentElement = [elementName copy];
  NSLog(@"didEndElement : %@",currentElement);

  if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"NewDataSet"]) {
    [dicEvent setObject:catIDArray forKey:@"term_id"];
    [dicEvent setObject:catArray forKey:@"cat_name"];
    [dicEvent setObject:catTimgArray forKey:@"thumb_nail_url"];
    [dicEvent setObject:catLimgArray forKey:@"large_image_url"];

    [xmlData addObject:[dicEvent copy]];  
  }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
  if ([catArray count] == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data" 
                               message:@"No record found." 
                              delegate:self
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                     otherButtonTitles:nil]; 

    [alert show];     
    [alert release];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"adding category : %@", xmlData);
    [tblView reloadData];
  }
}
```

and when table is loading i get error in this method....it is giving error on line return[xmlData count];

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  NSLog(@"[xmlData count] 2 : %d", [xmlData count]);
  return [xmlData count];
}
```

Comment: Please provide information where and how you define "xmlData"

Comment: Use NSZombieEnabled->YES and then try using debugging

Comment: Enable Zombie objects and see the error clearly then tell us. goto produc>edit schems> enable zombie objects

Answer (score 0):

There is a memory leak in the first method you posted. You create a copy of the `elementName` string but never release it. Also, you haven't specified how you intialise `xmlData` but I would hazard a guess and say that you initialised it with an array that you don't own. In your `init` method, make sure you have:

```
xmlData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This ensures that you own the object. In your `dealloc` method, you should have `[xmlData release]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *xmlData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and also put NSLog in